# Can Network Card cause high ping?

Tags: networking, ping

I have

```
windows 7 x64 
VoIP Modem. 
Arris Modem. 
12Mb cable internet 
ASUS P5K motherboard with built in Atheros L1 network card.
```

Few month ago my downloading speed started to slow down from 12mb to ~9mb and even slow as 3mb 
but upload speed remained high as usual.

I did:
- windows reinstall
- network drivers reinstalled
- firewall disabled
- antivirus removed and tried several same effect
- no viruses just few tracking cookies which were removed
- modem changed to a new one
- removed VoIP modem
- called ISP support they couldn't help me either
- changed LAN cable to a new one and still same effect
- deleted every software/program which may connect and download from internet

found out:
- if my computer connected to a modem, the ping on it extremely high as 400ms with 1% of packet loss 
but if it is not connected to my computer the ping as low as 40-20ms no packet loss. 
so the modem is fine 
- when restarted the speed return to normal and slowly goes down again.
- when I do ping test to Ping -t 8.8.8.8 it goes from 90ms up to 130ms every 4 sec.

Qs:

Can it be my Atheros Network card bad which cause high ping?

I can buy a new one for $20 TP-LINK .

Comment: Your diagnosis seems sound to me, it's a shame you don't have a spare PCI network card lying around somewhere to eliminate the onboard LAN as the problem without paying for a new one. But, you've narrowed the problem down to that particular computer, so swapping the NIC out is the next logical step.

Comment: What is your response time and packet loss to local devices? for example: have you setup a ping to your router or another local PC while pinging external hosts? It might help to compare the results.

Comment: Can the modem connect to your USB port?

Comment: If the network card was the culprit, ping to the router itself would get bad as well. You should test that.